# Java: How to detach a subprocess or create a detached process

Tags: java, process, subprocess, detach

Is it possible in Java to seperate a subprocess so that it isn't longer a subprocess in the end?
Or to run a external process, that isn't a subprocess.

I want to start some big external process in linux. But with ProcessBuilder or Runtime.exec, it's my subprocesses and when I try to start big processes for example four minecraft server, I get a pthread_create exception in the end.

Is this possible in Java?

Answer (score 0):

I just tested a small sample

```
import java.io.IOException;
public class Forking {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Process exec = null;
    try {
        exec = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sleep 360");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (exec != null) {
        System.out.println(exec.isAlive());
    }
  }
}
```

It runs with no exceptions and after it exits if you `ps aux|grep sleep` you will see that the sleep 360 is there running.